# Unable to login after removing Guest role view permission on landing/home page

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

While permissioning the pages created in Guest site, I `disable the view permission for Guest role` and `then log out`.

Now when I try to login, I can see `error message displaying permission error`.

I know one of the possible way to resolve it would be firing some `database query and enabling view permission for Guest role` so that I can atleast log in.

However Is there any other way to resolve this ?

Also It would be nice If anyone provides the database query for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach I found is to use Auto login functionality of liferay.

Following are the steps:

1) Add following property in portal-ext.properties

```
auto.login.hooks=com.liferay.portal.security.auth.CASAutoLogin,com.liferay.portal.security.auth.FacebookAutoLogin,com.liferay.portal.security.auth.NtlmAutoLogin,com.liferay.portal.security.auth.OpenIdAutoLogin,com.liferay.portal.security.auth.OpenSSOAutoLogin,com.liferay.portal.security.auth.RememberMeAutoLogin,com.liferay.portal.security.auth.SiteMinderAutoLogin,com.liferay.portal.security.auth.ParameterAutoLogin
```

2) Now start the server and go to

> LIFERAY_IP:LIFERAY_PORT?parameterAutoLoginLogin=ADMIN_USERNAME&parameterAutoLoginPassword=ADMIN_PASSWORD

i.e in my case

> localhost:8080?parameterAutoLoginLogin=test@liferay.com&parameterAutoLoginPassword=test

3)You will now be able to log in to portal and then go to control panel with /group/control_panel and modify the permission of page.